Table data not getting updated until i refresh the page
The issue I'm encountering is that when I add data to the database through a modal component, the new data doesn't immediately appear in the table. It only shows up after I refresh the page. I attempted to implement a refresh key logic to refetch the component, but it isn't working. I want the new data to be reflected in the table as soon as it's added through the modal, without requiring a manual refresh. The datatable component is where I'm calling both the modal and the table.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReviewFeature from "./ReviewFeature";
import ArtistModal from "./ArtistModal";
import Dropdown from "./Dropdown";
import Layout from "../../Components/Layout";
import { fetchReviewArtist, searchArtist } from "../../Services/Api";

const ReviewDataTable = () => {
  const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [dropdownVisible, setDropdownVisible] = useState(false);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [filteredItems, setFilteredItems] = useState([]);
  const [artists, setArtists] = useState([]);
  const [refreshKey, setRefreshKey] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchArtists = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetchReviewArtist();
        console.log("Fetched artists:", response);
        setArtists(response);
        console.log("set artist", setArtists);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching artists:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchArtists();
  },[refreshKey] );

  const fetchSpotifyArtists = async (query) => {
    try {
      const artists = await searchArtist(query);
      console.log("artists:", artists);
      setFilteredItems(artists);
      console.log("Filtered items:", artists);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching Spotify artistssssss:", error);
      setFilteredItems([]);
    }
  };

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: "",
    photo: "",
    location: "",
    bio: "",
    genre: " ",
    platforms: "",
    age: "",
    spotifyId: "",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchTerm) {
      fetchSpotifyArtists(searchTerm);
    } else {
      setFilteredItems([]);
    }
  }, [searchTerm]);

  const handleSelectArtist = async (artist) => {
    console.log("Artist before destrufture:", artist);
    const { name, photo, spotifyId } = artist;

    const artistImage = artist.image || "path/to/default/image.jpg";
    const artistGenres = "Unknown genre";

    const newFormData = {
      name,
      photo: artistImage,
      location: "",
      bio: "",
      genre: artistGenres,
      platforms: "",
      age: "",
      spotifyId: spotifyId,
    };

    setFormData(newFormData);
    console.log("Setting form data:", { name, photo: artistImage });
    setDropdownVisible(false);
    setModalIsOpen(true);
  };

  const openModal = () => {
    setModalIsOpen(true);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setModalIsOpen(false);
  };

  const addArtist = (newArtist) => {
    setArtists((prevArtists) => [...prevArtists, newArtist]);
     console.log("refreshkey:",refreshKey);
    closeModal();
  };

  const deleteArtist = (name) => {
    setArtists((prevArtists) =>
      prevArtists.filter((artist) => artist.name !== name)
     
    );
  };

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="flex flex-col w-full h-[500] overflow-y-auto bg-customBlue mt-12">
        <div className="p-4 bg-customBlue text-white overflow-hidden">
          <div className="flex flex-row gap-12">
            <h1
              className="text-2xl font-semibold text-white ml-10 mb-4"
              style={{ fontFamily: "Poppins" }}
            >
              Artists
            </h1>

            <div className="flex items-center space-x-4">
              <div className="relative flex flex-row">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Search for..."
                  value={searchTerm}
                  onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
                  onFocus={() => setDropdownVisible(true)}
                  className="p-2 pl-10 rounded-md border bg-customColor w-[260.75px] h-[46px] text-white mb-4"
                  style={{
                    borderRadius: "4px",
                    border: "0.6px solid  #343B4F",
                  }}
                />
                {/* <img
                  src="./assests/Search.png"
                  alt="Search Icon"
                  className="absolute left-3 top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2 w-5 h-5"
                /> */}
              </div>
            </div>
            <button
              onClick={openModal}
              className="w-[105px] h-[44px] bg-customBlue text-white mt-2 border-white rounded p-2 flex justify-center items-center"
              style={{
                border: "1px solid #ffffff",
                position: "relative",
                left: "630px",
              }}
            >
              <span className="font-poppins" style={{ whiteSpace: "nowrap" }}>
                + Add Artist
              </span>
            </button>
          </div>

          {dropdownVisible && searchTerm && (
            <Dropdown items={filteredItems} onSelect={handleSelectArtist} />
          )}

          <ReviewFeature data={artists} onDelete={deleteArtist} />

          <ArtistModal
            isOpen={modalIsOpen}
            onRequestClose={closeModal}
            onSave={(newArtist) => {
              addArtist(newArtist);
              setRefreshKey((oldKey) => oldKey + 1);
            }}
            preFilledData={{
              name: formData.name,
              photo: formData.photo,
              spotifyId: formData.spotifyId,
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default ReviewDataTable;


You are updating the state with setArtists and incrementing the refreshKey, but the refreshKey isn't triggering the re-fetch properly.
Try this:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReviewFeature from "./ReviewFeature";
import ArtistModal from "./ArtistModal";
import Dropdown from "./Dropdown";
import Layout from "../../Components/Layout";
import { fetchReviewArtist, searchArtist } from "../../Services/Api";

const ReviewDataTable = () => {
  const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [dropdownVisible, setDropdownVisible] = useState(false);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [filteredItems, setFilteredItems] = useState([]);
  const [artists, setArtists] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchArtists = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetchReviewArtist();
        console.log("Fetched artists:", response);
        setArtists(response);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching artists:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchArtists();
  }, []); // Only run on mount

  const fetchSpotifyArtists = async (query) => {
    try {
      const artists = await searchArtist(query);
      console.log("artists:", artists);
      setFilteredItems(artists);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching Spotify artists:", error);
      setFilteredItems([]);
    }
  };

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: "",
    photo: "",
    location: "",
    bio: "",
    genre: " ",
    platforms: "",
    age: "",
    spotifyId: "",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchTerm) {
      fetchSpotifyArtists(searchTerm);
    } else {
      setFilteredItems([]);
    }
  }, [searchTerm]);

  const handleSelectArtist = async (artist) => {
    const { name, photo, spotifyId } = artist;
    const artistImage = artist.image || "path/to/default/image.jpg";
    const artistGenres = "Unknown genre";

    const newFormData = {
      name,
      photo: artistImage,
      location: "",
      bio: "",
      genre: artistGenres,
      platforms: "",
      age: "",
      spotifyId: spotifyId,
    };

    setFormData(newFormData);
    setDropdownVisible(false);
    setModalIsOpen(true);
  };

  const openModal = () => {
    setModalIsOpen(true);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setModalIsOpen(false);
  };

  const addArtist = (newArtist) => {
    setArtists((prevArtists) => [...prevArtists, newArtist]);
    closeModal();
  };

  const deleteArtist = (name) => {
    setArtists((prevArtists) =>
      prevArtists.filter((artist) => artist.name !== name)
    );
  };

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="flex flex-col w-full h-[500] overflow-y-auto bg-customBlue mt-12">
        <div className="p-4 bg-customBlue text-white overflow-hidden">
          <div className="flex flex-row gap-12">
            <h1
              className="text-2xl font-semibold text-white ml-10 mb-4"
              style={{ fontFamily: "Poppins" }}
            >
              Artists
            </h1>

            <div className="flex items-center space-x-4">
              <div className="relative flex flex-row">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Search for..."
                  value={searchTerm}
                  onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
                  onFocus={() => setDropdownVisible(true)}
                  className="p-2 pl-10 rounded-md border bg-customColor w-[260.75px] h-[46px] text-white mb-4"
                  style={{
                    borderRadius: "4px",
                    border: "0.6px solid  #343B4F",
                  }}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <button
              onClick={openModal}
              className="w-[105px] h-[44px] bg-customBlue text-white mt-2 border-white rounded p-2 flex justify-center items-center"
              style={{
                border: "1px solid #ffffff",
                position: "relative",
                left: "630px",
              }}
            >
              <span className="font-poppins" style={{ whiteSpace: "nowrap" }}>
                + Add Artist
              </span>
            </button>
          </div>

          {dropdownVisible && searchTerm && (
            <Dropdown items={filteredItems} onSelect={handleSelectArtist} />
          )}

          <ReviewFeature data={artists} onDelete={deleteArtist} />

          <ArtistModal
            isOpen={modalIsOpen}
            onRequestClose={closeModal}
            onSave={(newArtist) => {
              addArtist(newArtist);
            }}
            preFilledData={{
              name: formData.name,
              photo: formData.photo,
              spotifyId: formData.spotifyId,
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default ReviewDataTable;


Adding an empty dependency in useEffect is't  working. As it will run once when component will mount .
